# the phrase "of all places"

Tags: idioms

*– And it was this man right here's trailer that you were in.*

*–  Yes.*

*–  And so that, **of all places**, you knew was important that you make sure that these Manitowoc officers not be alone.*

I would like to ask what the phrase "of all places" means in the context. I am not sure whether it has the idiomatic meaning or it means just that the police officers were not permitted to be alone in all the places in the property of the given man.

Comment: Your cited usage doesn't really make sense (it's certainly *syntactic* garbage). It's just clumsy phrasing where the speaker is regurgitating words in mangled form drawing on his earlier *And you knew that if anything, [**of all the places that they should not be alone,**](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=524&t=24361) it would be in Mr. Avery's trailer, right?*

Answer (score 3):

"of all places" is an English idiom and it means:

somewhere you would not immediately think of.

Take a look at the example sentence:

I always have lived in New York City and ended up going to school in Cornell, Iowa, of all places.

According to Cambridge dictionary:

of all people/things/places

used to ​express the ​idea that a ​particular ​person/thing/​place is ​unlikely or ​surprising.

Example sentences:

Donna, of all ​people, is the last one I'd ​expect to ​see at the ​gym.

And why did you ​choose Iceland for a ​holiday, of all ​places?

It can also be used for expressing surprise that a particular thing/person/place is the one involved in something.

Example:

And now she’s chosen to live in Alaska, of all places!

Comment: Thanks for a response. But the idiomatic meaning does not make for me much sense in my sentence. What is ​"unlikely or ​surprising"? Can you tell me the alternative phrase that fits in the context instead of "all of places".

Comment: It means that this man is the one involved.

Comment: Do you think that "under no circumstances" would be an appropriate substitution?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: i don't know exactly what this story is about.Is it possible for you to summarize it in your own words? I try my best to help you.

Comment: By this man i meant  "Mr. Avery"

Comment: It is a dialogue from the trial with - as you mentioned - S. Avery. Two police officers due to their conflicts of interest could not operate alone in the property of the suspect. They had to be watched by their colleagues from the another county. In your sentences the meaning of the phrase is clear. There is always mentioned the place (for example Iceland) but what is the place in my sentence? Is it the another county or the property of the suspect? It is very frustrating to be stuck in this may be detail.

Comment: I think this will help you understand this episode fully:The seventh episode of Making a Murderer, entitled “Framing Defense,” is unsurprisingly focused on the defense’s narrative that the Manitowoc County Sheriff’s Department framed Steven Avery for murder and, unsurprisingly, that narrative is framed entirely from the defense’s presumptions about motive and opportunity.

Read more: http://www.newstalk1130.com/onair/common-sense-central-37717/rebutting-a-murderer-episode-7-14273518/#ixzz45cHWmQNC

Comment: I have watched this episode as well as the previous ones of Making a Murderer with english subtitles. But now I am translating the subtitles into my native language. And I try to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: Understood. Let me sleep on it and I'll tell you my answer tomorrow. I don't want to rush my answer right now.

Comment: @bart-leby “[O]f all places” emphasizes that one place, *and not any other*. In my opinion, when you're emphasizing, it doesn't have to make sense like in the examples included in the answer above. So I think you're correct, the speaker made an unintentional mistake. There is another possibility, though highly unlikely, that the officers aren't allowed on other properties, and everyone involved knows about this.

Comment: I guess you are right.

Comment: @bart-leby. 
I asked a kind teacher and came up with this answer.Because of Mr. Avery's history with the Manitowoc police (he was suing the department for a large sum of money for wrongfully convicting him and putting him in prison when Mr. Avery had been innocent the whole time), the Manitowoc police definitely should not have been alone in his trailer. If the Manitowoc police were left alone, they might have planted fake evidence to make Mr. Avery look guilty. So the lawyer is making a point that everyone knew the Manitowoc police should not have been alone in Mr. Avery's trailer.

Comment: Thanks for your trying to help me. But in this case I would use the phrase  "of all people".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to phrase it might be,

> And so that, in any place, but most especially this place, you knew...

The idea is to convey that officers shouldn't be left alone anywhere, in any place (for contextually obvious reasons), but especially in one place - the trailer. (the trailer, of all places.)